# position of homescreen icons

Tags: android, icons, position, homescreen

Is it possible to organize the homescreen icons programatically so that i can arrange each icon's position?
thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific. What do you mean by "arrange each icon's position"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, bear in mind that there may be 50+ home screen applications, between custom ones for devices and third-party ones available off of the Android Market.

There are no requirements that any such application have the notion of "homescreen icons". There are no requirements that any such application have any sort of API for other apps to control the contents. The standard home screen that comes with the Android emulator does not have an API to "organize the homescreen icons programatically", nor does the Android SDK have such an API.

You are welcome to contact the developers of third-party home screens to convince them to add such an API, if they do not have one already.